# Deleting Qthread on the middle of running

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5, qthread

I created a thread with class A and after deleted class A, the thread is not deleted. It continues running.

I explicitly called the thread destructor, quit and exit function but still, the thread did not stop running.

Is there any thing like KILL function to stop the thread execution

```
void A::init()
{
    WorkerThread *Thread = new WorkerThread(this);
}

void B::slotClose()
{
    A *obj = getObj();
    if(obj)
    {
    m_pScene->removeItem(obj);
    obj->deleteLater(); // this calls thread distructor also but thread execution is not stopping
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Note that deleting a QThread object will not stop the execution of the thread it manages. Deleting a running QThread (i.e. isFinished() returns false) will result in a program crash. Wait for the finished() signal before deleting the QThread.

**You should never delete a running QThread object.**

So I think it would be the best for you to write some termination/quitting logic in your WorkerThread, expose some slot for example `quit` and connect signal with this `quit` slot.

If you just want to terminate the thread no matter  what, just connect destroyed SIGNAL to terminate SLOT (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#terminate)

So assuming your A class derives from QObject, what would you do inside this class is:

`connect(this, SIGNAL(destroyed()), Thread, terminate());`

If you have your own slot `quit` exposed, so you make sure you properly stop all that's executing in your loop just instead `terminate()` use `quit()`.

`connect(this, SIGNAL(destroyed()), Thread, quit());`

Here's an example of implementing such a logic: http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/

Or just put `quit = true` in your ThreadWorker destructor.

It should be straightforward. Good luck!

Also some official documentation with examples (imo doing it right):

https://wiki.qt.io/QThreads_general_usage

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qtnetwork-blockingfortuneclient-example.html

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.8/qtcore-threads-mandelbrot-example.html